# Can't get my .html files to save in chrome

Tags: save, microsoft-edge, notepad

When I click the "save as" button on Notepad and save it, it has the Edge icon instead of the Chrome one on the file icon and opens in Edge instead of Chrome[Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEfrB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your default browser is Edge.

Set your default browser to Chrome.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

As already informed by the other community member that on your machine, MS Edge legacy browser is set as a default browser.

That's why it is showing the Edge browser logo on the HTML file.

If you want to change your default browser then you can try to refer to the steps below.

1. Open **Settings** on your Windows 10 OS.
2. Click on **Apps**.
3. Click on the **Default apps** option from the left sidebar.
4. On the right side of the settings window, you can see the **web browser** option.
5. click on the browser will show you the list of the installed browsers on your machine. You can click on the desired browser to make it your default browser.

[image]

If you don't want to change the default browser then you can try to use the **Open with** option to open the HTML file with any other browser.

1. Select the HTML file.
2. Right-click on HTML file.
3. Hover the mouse pointer on **Open with** option. It will show you the list of the installed browsers.
4. You can click on the desired browser to open the file with that browser.

[image]